# keras.utils has no attribute get_file in linux

Tags: keras

I am trying to use this bagnet model - https://github.com/wielandbrendel/bag-of-local-features-models

installed it and imported it as per the instructions in this link ,

but when i am trying to use it as per the instructions -

bagnet_model = bagnets.kerasnet.bagnet33()

its showing error 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'get_file'

i already used this -
import segmentation_models as sm

sm.set_framework('tf.keras')

sm.framework()

and still not working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you look at the [github](https://github.com/wielandbrendel/bag-of-local-features-models/blob/master/bagnets/kerasnet.py), they are using
`keras.utils.get_file`. What I did was changing it to `keras.utils.all_utils.get_file`. The problem is that another issue occurrs : `ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)`, that was discussed [here](https://github.com/wielandbrendel/bag-of-local-features-models/issues/19). And I do not know what to do then.